# How can i echo this variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, echo

I have downloaded a script and i am attempting to modify it, i need to extract the username and echo it.
I am aware that to echo a variable like this:

```
<?php
echo $username;
?>
```

However gives me the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: username8
```

I asked the author how to echo the username variable and he replied with:

```
App::Auth()->username
```

I have not seen variables like this before and i have tried to echo it using:

```
<?php
echo $App::Auth()->username;
?>
```

However i get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: App8
Class name must be a valid object or a string [code: 0]
```

Whats the proper way to echo the username?
And is their a name for this type of variable to i can further research it?

Comment: `App::Auth()` not `$App::Auth()`, [static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) class method. Why are your variable names suffixed with `8`? You using a known PHP framework?

Comment: unfortunately I do not know as i have downloaded the script from code canyon

Comment: You can try `echo App::Auth()->username;`. Would need to see the code, otherwise just speculation. Reading the code is a good place to start. Gotta grok it to use it.

Comment: This worked, thankyou

Comment: @ficuscr I think that he has a 8 after the ?>

Comment: @MoisésMárquez weird right? Yeah, I was looking for a typo... missed shift, `*`? Beats me.

Comment: @ficuscr There is no 8 in the php file , i have no idea why 8 is appearing

Comment: Play the number 8 today if you are feeling lucky :)